# Kafka in Talend 8.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, talend

I started the Zookeeper and Kafka service which are on ubuntu2004. I also connect myself to my broker in Talend and create topics.

The problem is, using this same KafkaConnection, I am not able to send a message in bytes.

Here the flow in question :
[image]

With this job, Like I said, I succeed to connect to the broker to create a topics but not to send a message in bytes to my topic.

Here is the flow after I click on run :
[image]

And the error message :

```
[INFO ] 17:11:41 org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser- Kafka version : 1.1.0

[INFO ] 17:11:41 org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser- Kafka commitId : fdcf75ea326b8e07

[INFO ] 17:11:41 sandbox.kafkatopic_0_1.KafkaTopic- tFileInputDelimited_1 - Retrieving records from the datasource.

[INFO ] 17:11:41 sandbox.kafkatopic_0_1.KafkaTopic- tLogRow_2 - Content of row 1: test d'envois de message dans kafka

[INFO ] 17:11:41 sandbox.kafkatopic_0_1.KafkaTopic- tLogRow_1 - Content of row 1: test d'envois de message dans kafka

[WARN ] 17:11:43 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient- [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I use this Kafka version : kafka_2.13-3-2-1

For the records, in the KafkaConnection, I select the version 1.1.0 because with the newest version of kafka in this comp, I didn't even succeed to create a topic :

[image]

On a second time I tried to implement a SSL/TLS security. I am having issues with this too.

Comment: From the logs, please show output from `ProducerConfig` section. Also, you should definitely use 2.4.x connection if you have running Kafka 3.x

Comment: In your image, you have specified `localhost:2181`. 

This is Zookeeper, not Kafka. The Kafka connection should not require a Zookeeper string... Please try to provide only `localhost:9092` instead.